# Why do bad things happen to the innocent?

Tags: free-will, love, good-and-evil, theodicy, righteousness

OK, so to start, I searched this topic on the exchange and found no answers that were satisfying. I am not questioning God, I just have a hard time coming to terms with why bad things happen to the innocent. For instance, a mother through no fault of her own can't afford to feed her babies and has no means to do so except strip or other unsavory actions. Or, a young person who by all observable means did nothing to deserve developing an addiction to heroin.

Even with charity, and the good things Christians do, people will inevitably fall through the cracks. How is this fair? I know that God given free will plays a part, but if God saw the way these people, for better or for worse grew up, how can he still put them through unspeakable hardship, when they did nothing to deserve it?

I feel this question doesn't need references to prove what I am saying, all you have to do is look at the state of the world. These things happen on a daily basis. I ask because, I feel bad for these people and it is causing my faith to falter. I apologize if this doesn't meet the standards of the community, I did my best to adhere to them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil, https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/

Comment: https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/wp20140701/why-do-bad-things-happen/

Answer (score 5):

> people will inevitably fall through the cracks

Eternally? No. Not if they are repentant.

> For the Son of man is come to save that which was lost. (Matthew 18:11)

You might as well ask why Jesus, being the most innocent of all, had to suffer and die. He said, "Inasmuch as ye have done it unto one of the least of these my brethren, ye have done it unto me" (Matt. 25:40), therefore if any innocents suffer, does He not suffer? Why do the innocent suffer? He answered this question to His disciples on the Road to Emmaus, who wondered why Jesus had to die:

> Ought not Christ to have suffered these things, and to enter into his glory?

Or in other words, why would we shortsightedly refuse to suffer difficulty and shame for Christ's sake, knowing that eternal glory awaits?

[Russell M. Nelson](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2020/10/46nelson?lang=eng) relates such a case of innocent suffering, and addresses the malady of being concerned only with the now, the immediate and temporal outcomes:

> Not long ago, the wife of one of our grandsons was struggling spiritually. I will call her “Jill.” Despite fasting, prayer, and priesthood blessings, Jill’s father was dying. She was gripped with fear that she would lose both her dad and her testimony.
> Late one evening, my wife, Sister Wendy Nelson, told me of Jill’s situation. The next morning Wendy felt impressed to share with Jill that my response to her spiritual wrestle was one word! The word was *myopic*.

Such fears are *myopic* because they ignore the reality of the resurrection and the glory that awaits the faithful.
They neglect, in the words of the Risen Lord, "all that the prophets have spoken":

> Eye hath not seen, nor ear heard, neither have entered into the heart of man, the things which God hath prepared for them that love him. (1 Corinthians 2:9)

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the premise of your question:

> Why do bad things happen to the innocent?

Is this even valid? We don't know... because *humans aren't innocent*. We all share in Adam's Fall. We are all [sinful from birth](https://www.gotquestions.org/born-sinners.html).

> Behold, I was brought forth in iniquity, and in sin did my mother conceive me. (Psalm 51:5)

> Sin came into the world through one man, and death through sin, and so death spread to all people because all sinned (Romans 5:12)

Christ's teachings on Sin are uncompromising. If you have ever thought ill of someone, you are a murdered. If you have ever looked with desire on something (or someone) that isn't yours, you are a thief (and/or an adulterer). And so on. Who among us can honestly say they have never done such things? No, all people are sinful *by nature* and deserving of punishment, both now and for eternity.

Nevertheless, [couldn't God stop bad things from happening](https://www.gotquestions.org/God-allow-evil.html)? Well...

1. An integral part of God's Plan for humanity includes humans having Free Will. If God were to remove the ability of humans to do evil of any sort, Free Will wouldn't exist. God doesn't want robots, but people who *willingly* desire to be with Him.
2. If God were to intervene to prevent all evil from happening, life would be stifling. (If you've seen the movie adaptation of I, Robot, imagine that only much more restrictive.) Additionally, this might be the equivalent of shouting "I exist!" in everyone's faces all the time, which seems contrary to (1). Nor would this do anything about evil *thoughts* unless taken to the extreme of being the same as (1).
3. God could simply remove sinners from the world... in which case the human population would instantly become zero.
4. God could mitigate the worst evils... and He does! Movies and literature have plenty of examples of human evil allowed to run unfettered. I suspect many of those are only scratching the surface of how bad things would be if God did not act to hold evil back.
5. God could use other humans to mitigate evils... and He does! Unfortunately, those humans, being themselves fallible, don't always do as good a job as we might like, but the failing is *ours*, not God's.

While the [problem of evil](https://www.gotquestions.org/problem-of-evil.html) is hardly a new topic of discussion, it should also be kept in mind that God can use even Evil to bring about Good. Suffering builds character and can bring us closer to God (see Paul, Job), and God reveals Himself through our infirmities. Moreover, Christ teaches that those who suffer in this life are particularly blessed in the next (Matthew 5:3-12). In fact it is often claimed there is correlation between disadvantaged people and greater Faith (note also Matthew 19:23-34).

Answer (score 3):

God gave mankind free will.

God often calls upon people to help carry out His intentions, but people sometimes refuse.  This may make it necessary for God to find someone else, or accept that things don't always go according to plan.  While nothing would "physically" prevent God from forcing things to go as intended, the concept of free will would be meaningless if God did not treat it as inviolable.  Anything bad that happened would be a consequence of God allowing that bad thing to happen, rather than an inescapable consequence of a commitment to honor mankind's free will.

> Of all the gifts we have received
> None is more precious and more terrible.
> The will in each of us is free--
> It's in our hands -- Stephen Schwartz, *Children of Eden*

Comment: Interesting take. I would strongly disagree that God ever has to "Find someone else" or that "things don't always go according to plan". If God gives a command or direction and someone refuses, that was and always has been the plan, and the only plan.

Comment: @IsaacMiddlemiss: I disagree.  If one is playing Klondike Solitaire according to the rules, using real cards, one cannot peek at the cards buried in a stack unless or until one has removed the cards covering them.  Nothing would physically prevent a player from lifting up the cards and doing so, but a player who did so *would cease to be playing Klondike solitaire according to the rules*.  Nothing would have prevented God could have "peeked at all the cards" when he created mankind, but *had he done so he would not have given mankind free will*, and were he to do so *he would negate...*

Comment: *...mankind's free will*.  I don't know exactly what constraints God has imposed upon himself as part of giving mankind free will, but it must necessarily include an acceptance of things not always going to plan.

Comment: foreknowledge does not prevent free will. If God knows I'm going to have a banana for breakfast tomorrow, why does that force me to choose that? My choice causes His knowledge, not the other way around

Comment: @IsaacMiddlemiss: If at 8:00am tomorrow morning, you have a free will choice about whether to eat a banana or oatmeal, that would imply that at that moment you could make either choice without creating a contradiction.  If God could know at 8:00pm tonight that you will have a banana tomorrow, that would mean that at 8:00am it would be impossible for you to choose oatmeal tomorrow morning without creating a contradiction.

Comment: @IsaacMiddlemiss: Further, if God had sufficient foreknowledge that someone would do something bad that He could prevent it, but God failed to do so, that would imply that the bad thing happened not because the person decided to do it, but because God deliberately let it happen.

Answer (score 2):

Suffering is one of the means of communication with God. Since what is being communicated varies from person to person according to God’s purposes at the time, this means that the purpose of suffering is not the same for each person or each situation.

```
From its chamber comes the whirlwind,
   and cold from the scattering winds.
By the breath of God ice is given,
   and the broad waters are frozen fast.
He loads the thick cloud with moisture;
   the clouds scatter his lightning.
They turn around and around by his guidance,
   to accomplish all that he commands them
   on the face of the habitable world.
Whether for correction or for his land
   or for love, he causes it to happen. (Job 37:9-13, ESV)
```

The preceding quote from Job gives insight into the reasons for powerful storms, an analogy for all of suffering. One is correction for wrongdoing. One is common grace, supplying water for the crops to grow. The last is for love. So one reason God sends suffering is because He loves us. In Job, one whirlwind killed his ten children while the second was a theophany where God appeared. This emphasizes the point.

A few years ago, I wrote a book about Job. One discovery was that the book mentions over a dozen ways that God and man can communicate, one of them being suffering. Out of his suffering, Job formulated a set of requirements that a savior would have to meet in order to save him from his many problems. I called this list his “job requirements for a savior”. The list of eight requirements (which grew to nine in a subsequent book) described the life and ministry of Jesus very well. So suffering was one of God’s means of teaching Job about the savior.

In my life, I endured many years of suffering. When a long season of trials was near to ending, I turned to Job and understood the message much clearer than ever before. God used my suffering to teach me the meaning of Job.

There is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is natural for sinners like whores and addicts to blame God or society for their own sins, they cannot rid their responsibilities for their failings. The examples of evil you gave are all volition and intentional transgression, rather than suffering or calamities on the innocent; however, all general suffering, pain and consequence of sin can be explained by postulating God's reasons for allowing them for a purpose. This is an argument against probability of God's existence, which simply wonders that God shouldn't allow this much of evil and suffering.

The [probabilistic problem of evil](https://www.bethinking.org/suffering/the-problem-of-evil) is an argument that suggests it is improbable that God exists, given the evil in the world. This argument is based on the idea that the existence of evil makes it unlikely that an omnipotent and omnibenevolent God exists. The argument is more modest than the purely logical problem of evil, which aims to show that it is logically impossible for both God and evil to exist.

The probabilistic problem of evil can be summarized as follows:

1. The existence of evil in the world is improbable if God exists.
2. The existence of evil in the world is probable.
3. Therefore, it is improbable that God exists.

This argument is based on the idea that the existence of evil in the world is more probable than the existence of an omnipotent and omnibenevolent God.

In response to this argument, it can be pointed out that probabilities are relative to the background information one considers. For example, if we consider the full scope of the evidence, God's existence may still be probable. Additionally, it can be argued that God may have morally sufficient reasons for permitting the evil in the world, even if these reasons are not immediately apparent to us.

The reasons for permitting sin and suffering is to present a test for man and to draw them in a relationship to work with them.

Answer (score 1):

The physical bad things (murder, robbery, enslavement, etc.) that occur in our world are the result of spiritually bad things (greed, hate, and above all, pride) that occur in the hearts of men.

Those of use who grow spiritually will eventually come to the knowledge that the spiritual ills are worse than the physical ones, so much so that even if it were possible to entirely prevent the physical ills, leaving the spiritual ills uncorrected, the difference would not be worthy of mention.

Hence, the physical ills are allowed so that we can recognize spiritual problems for what they are.

As for why they happen to the *innocent*, that is simple to recognize: Would we even recognize murder or robbery as evil if they only happened to bad people? Clearly not.

So, as with just about everything else that God permits, bad things happen to innocent people so that we can know what sin is.

Answer (score 1):

On Boxing Day 2004 a massive earthquake in the Indian Ocean, the third largest earthquake on record. The earthquake happened in the very early hours of Sunday morning.  The death toll continued to climb for several days. The tsunami was finally believed to have killed nearly a quarter of a million people.  In the evening of that Sunday a London Pastor preached on a passage in the Gospel of Luke:

> There were present at that season some that told him of the Galilaeans, whose blood Pilate had mingled with their sacrifices.  And Jesus answering said unto them, Suppose ye that these Galilaeans were sinners above all the Galilaeans, because they suffered such things?  I tell you, Nay: but, except ye repent, ye shall all likewise perish.  Or those eighteen, upon whom the tower in Siloam fell, and slew them, think ye that they were sinners above all men that dwelt in Jerusalem?  I tell you, Nay: but, except ye repent, ye shall all likewise perish. (Luke 13:1-5)

These two events sum up all the different kinds of evil that happen in the world.. some are manmade and some are natural disasters.

Sometimes bad things happen as a warning that soon we shall stand before a holy God and give an account of our lives.  And if we have not repented then we shall suffer an eternal punishment.  Sometimes a child receives a punishment as an act of kindness.. they were playing too close to an open fire and seemed intent on seeing how close they could get.. or they were running into the road to see if they could get across before an approaching car.  God gives out warnings to us all.. the worst thing that could possibly happen is stand before Him in judgement without a saviour, without someone to pay for our sins.  And only Jesus, the Son of God and second person of the Trinity, can pay for anyone else's sins.

Jesus said something else in Luke's Gospel that is relevant to this question:

> And I say unto you, Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye shall find; knock, and it shall be opened unto you.  For every one that asketh receiveth; and he that seeketh findeth; and to him that knocketh it shall be opened.  If a son shall ask bread of any of you that is a father, will he give him a stone? or if he ask a fish, will he for a fish give him a serpent?  Or if he shall ask an egg, will he offer him a scorpion?  *If ye then, being evil*, know how to give good gifts unto your children: how much more shall your heavenly Father give the Holy Spirit to them that ask him?  (Luke 11:9-13)

In this passage our Lord clearly tells us we are all evil.  He says it so matter of factly, nonchalantly even? For him it is clearly beyond any dispute.. all humanity is evil.

With the exception of those who die in infancy, there is only one person who has been truly innocent throughout their lives: the Lord Jesus Christ. Those babes who die in infancy, before they have reached an age of discretion - an age known only to God in each case - go straight to heaven because Christ has paid the price for their sinful nature.

So God sometimes allows bad things happen to (evil) people as a warning to others.  God sometimes allows bad things to happen to purify our hearts.. we love the things of this world over-much.. we have lost focus we are just passing through this world.. God chastens his children that they might repent and thus escape the punishment that is coming on the whole world.

> Before I was afflicted I went astray, but now have I kept your word.. it is good for me that I have been afflicted that I might learn your statutes. (Psalm 119:67..71)

However...

> He does not willingly afflict nor grieve the children of men. (Lamentations 3:33)

And God allows his children to suffer that the world might see how much they love their Lord and Saviour..

> Go your way, for he [the Apostle Paul] is my chosen vessel, to bear my name before the Gentiles, and kings, and the children of Israel:  for I will show him how greatly he must suffer for my name's sake.  (Acts 9:15-16)

When people suffer terrible things it takes our hearts off the love of this world, and makes us long for that place where there will be no more tears, nor any sin, that place that is only for those who have turned back to God and trusted in the Saviour of sinners, Jesus Christ.

God has his purposes in all that happens, sometimes it seems impossible to see why he would allow such things to happen.  That is where faith comes in.  We hold onto the belief that *God is good and does good* (Psalm 119:68), that *the steadfast love of the LORD never ceases, his mercies never come to an end, they are knew every morning, great is thy faithfulness* (Lamentations 3:22-23).

What a terrible world it would be if there is no God!  No one to turn to for comfort, no one to ask for mercy from, and no punishment for the likes of a Hitler, a Stalin or a Chairman Mao.  How unbearably cruel can people be to other people!  How can anyone bear to think of all the evil in the world if there is no Day of Judgement from our all-seeing, just and holy God?